# things that affect the apk file size

Tags: android, kotlin

what are the ways to reduce the apk file size? 
and what are the things affecting it?
I noticed sometimes when I build the apk, the size goes above 100k and other times it will be around 20k what is the thing it depends on exactly?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dynamiclist"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.2'
    api 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.0.2'

    implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
```

this is the gradele that I have used when it reached 100k if that helps

Comment: If you build apk using release variant, what is the size and if build apk using debug what is the size. I believe release build may have 20k size because of minifyEnabled

Comment: try using apk analyzer function of android studio. there you can see which file is taking what size in your apk Build>Analyze Apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to Analyse the apk file which gives the information of how much Size allocated to the Resources......

so for analyze apk for Build Apk using:-

```
Build > Build Bundles(s)/APK(s) > Build APK(s).
```

After the Build Apk you can analyse your apk using:-

```
Build > Analyze APK...
```

this will Gives you the information about the Size are taken by Resources.
using which you can Remove unwanted Resources for Decrease Apk size.

I am sure This will Help you for Decrease The Apk Size..